# Groovy - Convert object to JSON string

Tags: json, groovy

I'm pretty used to Grails converters, where you can convert any object to a JSON representation just like this (http://grails.org/Converters+Reference)

```
return foo as JSON
```

But in plain groovy, I cannot find an easy way to do this (http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)

```
JSONObject.fromObject(this)
```

return empty json strings...

Am I missing an obvious Groovy converter ? 
Or should I go for jackson or gson library ?

Comment: native "groovy properties" are not known to pure java libraries (i.e. libraries working on java reflection / java beans)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Do you mean like:

```
import groovy.json.*

class Me {
    String name
}

def o = new Me( name: 'tim' )

println new JsonBuilder( o ).toPrettyString()
```

Comment: This is indeed working. But the crazy thing, is if you specify "public String name". If you use public accessor, JsonBuilder seems to ignore them...

Comment: @Wavyx Yeah, then it doesn't make it into `metaClass.properties`, so isn't picked up by the builder :-/

Comment: Ok.. only other ugly solutions was
`def toJsonString(Boolean prettyPrint = false) {
        Map props = [:]
        def outObject = Publication.declaredFields.findAll { !it.synthetic && it.name != 'props' }.collectEntries { v ->
            [ (v.name):this[v.name] ]
        }
        outObject << props
        String json = JsonOutput.toJson(outObject)
        prettyPrint ? JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json) : json
    }`

Comment: Or maybe: `new JsonBuilder( this.getClass().declaredFields.findAll { !it.synthetic }.collectEntries { [ (it.name):this[ it.name ] ] } ).toString()`

Answer (score 30):

I couldn't get the other answers to work within the evaluate console in Intellij so...

```
groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(myObject)
```

This works quite well, but unfortunately

```
groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyString(myObject)
```

didn't work for me.

To get it pretty printed I had to do this...

```
groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(myObject))
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) for that.

Example Code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

class Person {
    String name
    String address
}

def o = new Person( name: 'John Doe', address: 'Texas' )

println new JsonBuilder( o ).toPrettyString()
```